# How to increase brightness and change activity at once on a click of a button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating an flashlight app which has many options for lightening. One of these options is Bright White Light. I want a code that when I click that button, the brightness is increased to 100% and i go to another activity at once and when I press back button (the one which is in the phone). The brightness again comes to the original level.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: But why are you shouting?

Comment: @Mureinik i am not shouting! :)

Comment: Another Android Flashlight app? That vertical seems saturated. Be sure to ask for nearly every permission the device offers.

Comment: Do you want to use the screen as the light source or the camera LED flash?

Comment: @gilonm I want to use the screen as the light source.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code example:

inside your `onCreate()` method, put this:

```
    //Button findViewById...

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);

editor.putInt("curBrightnes", "curBrightnessValue"); // Storing current screen brightness in SharedPrefs
editor.commit();


//Incase screen is at full brightness after clicking button - reset brightness to previous value
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
        int oldBrightness - pref.getInt("curBrightnes", 0.5);
        layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float)oldBrightness;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);



    //When you click the button, change brightness to max and go to other Activity
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layoutParams.screenBrightness = 100.0f; //sets brightness to maximum
        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

                              Intent i = new Intent(yourActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
                              startActivity(i); //go to next Activity
                            }
                    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Like I have mentioned in my answer - inside your onCreate() method. Please also change your button and activity names according to your project